# ReactJS - use the same hook in different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a hook that is fetching data from an api and the result I am putting in the state of my component with `setAllCommunitiesFromSponsor`.

Now I need to use the exact same hook in another component.

In this case, what is the proper way to implement this besides copy paste? I need to create a custom hook? But what about the setState function?

**the hook:**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getAllCommunitiesFromSponsor = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await api.get(
          'https://someurl.com'
        )
        const resultArray = Object.values(result.data.rows)
        setAllCommunitiesFromSponsor(resultArray)
      } catch (error) {
        toast.error('Failed to fetch data from the server')
      }
    }
    getAllCommunitiesFromSponsor()
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own hook, it's extremely simple. It's just a function that uses hooks. In your case:

```
const useCommunitiesForSponsor = () => {
    const [allCommunitiesFromSponsor, setAllCommunitiesFromSponsor] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        const getAllCommunitiesFromSponsor = async () => {
            try {
                const result = await api.get(
                    'https://someurl.com'
                )
                const resultArray = Object.values(result.data.rows)
                setAllCommunitiesFromSponsor(resultArray)
            } catch (error) {
                toast.error('Failed to fetch data from the server')
            }
        }
        getAllCommunitiesFromSponsor()
    }, [])

    return allCommunitiesFromSponsor;
}
```

Now in your components simply use the hook like any other hook:

```
const allCommunitiesFromSponsor = useCommunitiesForSponsor();
```